# App retornando android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: java, android

Galera estou tendo esse erro quando tento abrir a camera do dispositivo, percebi quando abro o fragment da camera apos outro fragment que salva imagem na galeria. Segue codigo:

Fragment da Camera:

```
public class FotoFragment extends Fragment {
ImageView imageViewFoto;
Button btnTiraFoto;
Button btnFinalizar;
Bitmap bitmap2 = null;
String currentPhotoPath;
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;


public FotoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_fragment, container, false);

    imageViewFoto = root.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFotoCasa);
    btnTiraFoto = root.findViewById(R.id.btnTirarFoto);
    btnFinalizar = root.findViewById(R.id.btnFinalizarEntrega);

    btnTiraFoto.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        tirarFoto();
    });

    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.fotografar_casa).asGif().into(imageViewFoto);

    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentPhotoPath);
            Picasso.get().load(new File(currentPhotoPath)).into(imageViewFoto);
            btnFinalizar.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    btnFinalizar.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if(bitmap2 != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Foto Salva!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Favor Tirar foto antes de finalizar!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

    return root;
}

public void tirarFoto(){
    Intent intent = null;
    File foto = null;

    try{
        foto = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    if( foto != null ){
        Uri fotoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                "com.example.caetanoentrega.fileprovider",
                foto);

        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fotoUri);
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);

    }

}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Cria nome para a foto tirada
    String imageFileName = "casa"; //Aqui sera renomeada casa+pedido
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"CaetanoEntrega/");
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",   /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Fragment da Assinatura

```
public class PaintViewFragment extends Fragment {

private SignaturePad signaturePad;
private Button btnLimpar;
private Button btnSalvar;
private EditText txtNome;
private EditText txtCPF;

public PaintViewFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.paint_view_fragment, container, false);
    signaturePad = root.findViewById(R.id.signature_pad);
    txtCPF = root.findViewById(R.id.txtDocRecebeu);
    txtNome = root.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeRecebeu);
    btnLimpar = root.findViewById(R.id.btnLimpar);
    btnSalvar = root.findViewById(R.id.btnSalvar);
    signaturePad.setOnSignedListener(new SignaturePad.OnSignedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartSigning() {
            //Event triggered when the pad is touched
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Assinar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSigned() {
            //Event triggered when the pad is signed
            btnSalvar.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClear() {
            //Event triggered when the pad is cleared
            btnSalvar.setEnabled(false);
            //btnLimpar.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    btnLimpar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (btnLimpar.getText().toString().equals("Assinar")) {
                if (txtCPF.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAVOR PREENCHER CPF!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    txtCPF.setHintTextColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 0, 0));
                    txtCPF.setHint("**INFORMAR CPF");
                } else if (txtNome.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAVOR PREENCHER NOME!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    txtNome.setHintTextColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 0, 0));
                    txtCPF.setHint("**INFORMAR NOME COMPLETO");
                } else {
                    btnLimpar.setText("Limpar");
                    txtCPF.setEnabled(false);
                    txtNome.setEnabled(false);
                    btnLimpar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.laranja));
                    signaturePad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }else{
                signaturePad.clear();
            }
        }
    });

    btnSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bitmap signatureBitmap = signaturePad.getSignatureBitmap();
            if (addJpgSignatureToGallery(signatureBitmap)) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Assinatura Salva!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onStop();
                onDestroyView();
                onDestroy();
                abreFoto("234");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Não foi possivel salvar assinatura!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    return root;
}

public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName){
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if(!file.mkdir()){
        Log.e("CaetanoEntrega", "Diretorio não criado");
    }
    return file;
}

public void saveBitmapToJPG(Bitmap bitmap, File photo) throws IOException{
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),  bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(photo);
    newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
    stream.close();
}

public boolean addJpgSignatureToGallery(Bitmap signature){
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        File photo = new File(getAlbumStorageDir("CaetanoEntrega"), String.format("Signarure.jpg"));
        saveBitmapToJPG(signature, photo);
        //scanMidiaFile(photo);
        result = true;
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public void scanMidiaFile(File photo){
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

public void abreFoto(String idPedido){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("idPedido",idPedido);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, FotoFragment.class,bundle)
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .addToBackStack("Fragment3")
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Erro:

2022-03-17 17:47:58.595 19342-19342/com.example.caetanoentrega E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.caetanoentrega, PID: 19342
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 6805536 bytes
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 6805536 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1145)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:3891)
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
2022-03-17 17:47:58.637 19342-19342/com.example.caetanoentrega I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19342 SIG: 9

Acontece no momento que chamo tirarfoto()

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi adicionando a minha activity:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle oldInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(oldInstanceState);
    oldInstanceState.clear();
}
```